# VB.Net changing Button image by selecting Combobox item

Tags: vb.net, image, button, combobox

I'm pretty sure that it *must* work but I don't get it working.

So maybe you can help me.

I got a Combobox with some items (item1-item7) to select and 54ish Buttons(sButton1-sButton54). Also an array(53) called Buttons. The array is filled with the items to select, like: Buttons(0) = "item 1, item 2"

Everytime another item in the Combobox is selected, I'd like only some of the Buttons to change their Image. Therefore I got the array. If Item 1 is selected and Buttons(0) contains the item1 I'd like to change the Button1's image.

edit: It works with changing the image of every Button:

```
sButton1.Image = My.Resources.image1
```

---

### But I'd prefer to change all in one go (Loop) instead.

```
sButton(0) = "item1, item2, item3"
sButton(1) = "item2, item3"
sButton(2) = "item1, item3"
```

...

```
Select Case ComboBox.SelectedItem

Case "item1"
                    For i = 0 To 53
                        If sButton(i).Contains("item1") Then
                            'sButton1.Image = My.Resources.image1
                            Me.Controls("sButton" & ((i + 1).ToString)).Enabled = True
                            Me.Controls("sButton" & ((i + 1).ToString)).Visible = True
                        Else
                            Me.Controls("sButton" & ((i + 1).ToString)).Enabled = False
                            Me.Controls("sButton" & ((i + 1).ToString)).Visible = False
                        End If
                    Next
```

Comment: You edit changes the question substantially as nothing was mentioned about looping in the initial question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. As you already said I edited the question, because I did a big mistake. I mixed up a question I had before but which I could solve on my own. It took me some time to edit this while you were answering my first question. This is why it went wrong. I am sorry - it wasn't my intention to be a trouble for you.

Answer (score 0):

First I would declare a form scope variable

```
Dim imglist As New ImageList
```

on the form load event:

```
call LoadImageList:
```

Which will populate you imageList with images  and a key for each image

In LoadImageList add an entry for each image you wish to have available for the button.

```
Private Sub LoadImageList()
    Me.ImageList1.Images.Add("key that matches the text in your combobox (Frog)", New Bitmap("c:\pathtoyourimages.jpg"))
    Me.ImageList1.Images.Add("Dog", New Bitmap("c:\dog.jpg"))
    'Do this for each images and you will have an image list that can be used to change you button.

End Sub
```

Next you will need a handler for your combobox click.

```
      Private Sub cmbYourCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbUserPassword.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim cmb As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
    If cmb IsNot Nothing Then ' This line checks to ensure that only a combobox is able to trigger this event.
        Me.btnSave.Image = imglist.Images(cmb.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you need help implementing this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to populate the ComboBox with structures that list the state of each button.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Structure ButtonConfig
        Public Text As String
        Public ButtonStates As Boolean()

        Public Sub New(Text As String, ButtonStates As Boolean())
            Me.Text = Text
            Me.ButtonStates = ButtonStates
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Text
        End Function
    End Structure

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(New ButtonConfig("Config 1", New Boolean() {True, True, False, False, ...}))
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(New ButtonConfig("Config 2", New Boolean() {True, False, True, False, ...}))
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(New ButtonConfig(...)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Dim ButtonStates As Boolean() = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, ButtonConfig).ButtonStates
            Dim ButtonState As Boolean
            For Index As Integer = 0 To ButtonStates.Length - 1
                ButtonState = ButtonStates(Index)
                With Me.Controls("sButton" & ((Index + 1).ToString))
                    .Enabled = ButtonState
                    .Visible = ButtonState
                End With
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```